# Special map $f(x_n)=x_{{n+1} [\mod 4]}$

Tags: recurrence-relations, special-functions, dynamical-systems

As mentioned in the headline I am considering the map $f(x_n)=x_{{n+1} [\mod 4]}$. It looks a little bit similar to the dyadic (bernoulli) map but instead of $\mod 1$ we have $\mod 4$ which means that in the binary representation after each step we move the coma $4$ steps to the right (am I correct?)

I also have $4$ points $x_0<x_1<x_2<x_3$. These are the members of a $4$-cycle with $f(x_n)$. Now I want to prove the existence of a fixed point, a 2 cycle and 3 cycle of $f(x_n)$. I do not see why it has to follow from the fact that there exists a 4 cycle that there are also other cycles and a fixed point. It might be possible to prove it using the intermediate value theorem. Do yo have any idea?

Comment: $f$ is just a permutation on $4$ points.

Comment: Can you give me an example of such a permutation using the function above? I have some difficulties using this notation.

Comment: Please explain or improve your strange notation $f(x_n)=x_{{n+1} [\mod 4]}$, so that we can understand what $f$ does.

Comment: The problem is I do not understand the notation by myself properly, I thought it has similarities to the dyadic transformation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_transformation)as mentioned above but Leox thinks it is just a permutation on 4 points

Comment: If I'm understanding what you wrote correctly, it cannot be the case that the 4 points you listed are the members of a 4-cycle under $f$. We see that $f(x_3) = x_{4 \mod 4} = x_0$. Where did you come across this notation?

Comment: It came up in one of my exmaple sheets referring to ode's/dynamical systems but no reference was made to the lecture